# Less "convenient" way to get first IP assigned to eth0 in Java?

Tags: java

The [javadoc for NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) says it's a *Convenience method to return an Enumeration with all or a subset of the InetAddresses bound to this network interface*.

**I'm trying to get the first IP address assigned to `eth0`**. When you call `getInetAddresses()`, you end up getting all IPs addresses assigned to the interface, including aliases, but in seemingly random order. You then have to call `getSubInterfaces()` to find and then strip out all the IPs assigned to `eth0:1`, `eth0:2`, etc. See [my gist here](https://gist.github.com/skehlet/4a10edc39482091569e3) for what I'm doing. It seems like it works, I guess.

**Edit:** my gist successfully filters out IP aliases added with `ifconfig eth0:n ...` but not those added with `ip addr add ...`.

I'm wondering about the word "convenience" in the javadoc. Does it mean there is a *less convenient* way that I could get InetAddresses on an interface, that's better suited for what I'm trying to do? If so, any pointers/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a concept of "first" IP assigned to an adapter.  It listens to all of them equally and there's no sense of priority. They may be numbered by the OS but that's just to give them unique names.

Comment: @JimGarrison I would tend to agree with you generally, but there is a specific reason in this case I want the "original" IP versus any secondary IPs added later. Also, if you run `ip addr ls` it puts the word `secondary` next to any additional IPs after the first. Maybe I'll just have to shell out to get this info.

Comment: Again, make sure your definitions of "first" and "later" are have a consistent meaning.  Suppose the adapter is given address `A` "first", and then `B` and `C`. Then later `A` is unassigned and replaced with `D`. What is "first"?

Comment: @JimGarrison good point. I realize now my approach of trying to autodetect the "first/original/primary" IP is wrong. I'll need to rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds convenient. You just call this method and get all addresses.

In a low level way you would have to get the interfaces first and than gather the information from each interface. For getting the interfaces you would need some kind of access to your hardware. The hardware access would probably be operation system dependent.

Would you like to worry about the hardware access based on your operation system or does sound getting all information you need with a simple method call convenient?

Comment: This will only ever be run on Linux, so I suppose it's okay to just shell out and call `ip` or `ifconfig` or parse `/proc` or something. I was really just getting hung up on the doc, which was tantalizingly suggesting there might be another way elsewhere via Java. Why would they bother putting the word *convenient* if there wasn't? Then wouldn't everything in the Java SDK be about convenience? "As opposed to doing <blank> yourself, we've provided it in the SDK as a convenience..."